# Remove All Smalltalk Comments for Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string, comment

- Take a line of input (function arguments or stdin, [etc.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/90614)).
- Remove comments in it, where a comment starts and ends with `"`.
- Do not remove comments in string literals, which start and end with `'`. String literals do not contain escapes, because smalltalk has nice, easily lexable syntax ;).
- [Output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/90614) this string.
- The number of `"`s not inside strings and the number of `'`s not in comments in the input are both guaranteed to be even.
- Because removing comments makes programs more golfy, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): shortest code per language wins.

### Examples

`input => output`

```
123 => 123
1"2"3 => 13
1""23 => 123
'12' => '12'
'1"2'3"" => '1"2'3
'1"2"3' => '1"2"3'
a"1'2'3"a => aa
"a"b"c" => b
'a'b'c' => 'a'b'c'
a'"'b'"'c => a'"'b'"'c
a"'"b"'"c => abc
```

<sub>Regex is boring as usual. Try [something](https://tryapl.org) [new](https://www.jsoftware.com/), or answer in smalltalk!</sub>

Comment: [sandboxed ;)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22402/90614)

Comment: This would be a good use-case for graphical programming languages for statecharts! Unfortunately, graphical programming languages are not good for golfing.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Remember that this isn't a competition between languages. I'd still be interested in a solution using one of those languages, even if it isn't competitive *with a dedicated golfing language*.

Answer (score 9):

## [Smalltalk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php), 325 bytes

```
[:k|k inject:OrderedCollection new into:[:a :b|(a isEmpty not and:[a last=0])ifTrue:[(b=$')ifTrue:[a removeLast. a add:b. a]ifFalse:[a removeLast. a add:b. a add:0. a]]ifFalse:[(a isEmpty not and:[a last=$"])ifTrue:[(b=$")ifTrue:[a removeLast. a]ifFalse:[a]]ifFalse:[(b=$')ifTrue:[a add:b. a add:0. a]ifFalse:[a add:b. a]]]]]
```

Some hot garbage smalltalk code.

It essentially uses a stack, pushing a `0` for a placeholder for when it sees `'`. When it sees `"`, it keeps in on the top of the stack until it sees another `"`.

I couldn't get an Eval function (smalltalk docs are *terrible*), nor could I get regex to work (smalltalk docs are *terrible*).

You can use GNU Smalltalk to run this, in theory, although I only tested it on the online compiler (linked above).

Here's a (more) readable version that takes from stdin and writes to stdout. As you can tell smalltalk is a beautiful language...

```
Transcript show:(stdin nextLine inject:
    OrderedCollection new into:
        [:a :b|
        
        Transcript show: a printString; cr.

        (a isEmpty not and:[a last = 0])ifTrue: [
            (b = $') ifTrue: [
                a removeLast.
                a add: b.
                a
            ] ifFalse:[
                a removeLast.
                a add: b.
                a add: 0.
                a
            ]
        ] ifFalse: [
            (a isEmpty not and:[a last = $"]) ifTrue: [
                (b = $") ifTrue: [
                    a removeLast.
                    a
                ] ifFalse: [a]
            ] ifFalse: [
                (b = $') ifTrue: [
                    a add: b.
                    a add: 0.
                    a
                ] ifFalse: [
                    a add: b.
                    a
                ]
            ]
        ]
]).
```

Note: the regex solution almost works, using the same approach as Jakque, but it fails since smalltalk gives `nil` instead of an empty string:

```
Transcript show:(stdin nextLine replacingAllRegex: '".*?"|(''.*?''|.)' with: '%1')
```

Comment: By "the online compiler" you mean [codingground](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php)?

Comment: yes I do mean that

Comment: I didn't know about character literals in smalltalk. Because of those, this challenge won't work on real smalltalk code :/

Comment: `Transcript show: 'a"''"b"''"c'` "works", but single quotes get escaped by placing... another single quote.

Edit: nvm it doesn't work since it's not parsed as code, duh.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>30</s> 26 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous prefix lambda.

```apl
{⍵/⍨≠\⍛⍱⍨<⌿≠\@1⊢'''"'∘.=⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR71b9R70rHnUuiHnUO/tR70Ygx@ZRz36QgIPho65F6urqSuqPOmbo2QKV1v5Pe9Q24VFv36Ou5ke9ax71bjm03vhR28RHfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/NHVDI2N1LiClZKQEZShBRNSBUkACwlICMo2VlOA8oFqwVKKSobo6WC4RxFVKVEpSSoYqS1RXT1JXT4YqBLkNxFcCCYF1AtlJICJZHQA)

`{`…`}` [dfn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_function); argument is `⍵`:
  `` `a"1'2'3"a'1"2"3'a"'"b"'"c` ``

`'''"'∘.=⍵` equality table for `'` and `"` versus the argument
   `[[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],`
    `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]]`

`≠\@1⊢` running parity (lit. XOR scan) **at** the 1st row (lit XOR scan) indicating characters inside strings
   `[[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],`
    `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]]`

`<⌿` second row, i.e. comment delimiters, and not first row, i.e. inside string, i.e. active comment delimiters (lit. vertical less-than reduce)
   `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]`

`≠\⍛⍱⍨` neither that (active comment delimiters) NOR its running parity (inside comments)
   `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`

`⍵/⍨` use that to filter the characters of the argument
   `` `aa'1"2"3'ac` ``

Comment: it's nice to see that the regex solution and the cool and refreshing solution are the same length in APL

Comment: @Wzl Shorter, even.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 48 bytes

```
iⱮ⁾'"o1:0¤>/
ṣ”"2œPj€”"µẹ”'2ị‘œṖµÇ?;ß}¥/$¹f⁾'"$?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/z0cZ1jxr3qSvlG1oZHFpip8/1cOfiRw1zlYyOTg7IetS0BsQ@tPXhrp1AhrrRw93djxpmHJ38cOe0Q1sPt9tbH55fe2ipvsqhnWlgU1Ts////n6iupJ4ExMlK6kopQJwKAA)

This is definitely not the best approach, even considering Jelly is typically not great with strings.

````
iⱮ⁾'"o1:0¤>/  Helper Link
iⱮ⁾'"         Find the first ' and "; 0 if not found
     o        Logical OR with
      1:0¤    1 / 0 (infinity) - that way, "not found" is at the end, not the start
          >/  Is the first greater than the second?

ṣ”"2œPj€”"µẹ”'2ị‘œṖµÇ?;ß}¥/$¹f⁾'"$?  Main Link
                                  ?  If
                             f⁾'"$   There are any ' or "
                     ?     $         - If
                    Ç                - " was found first
ṣ”"                                    - Split on "
   2œP                                 - Split over and discard the second item
      j€”"                             - Join each of those with " (basically, this slices out
                                         the part between and including the first and second ",
                                         and leaves the part before and after as two sublists)
                                     - Otherwise
           ẹ”'                         - Find all indices of '
              2ị                       - Get the second of these
                ‘                      - And increment it
                 œṖ                    - And partition the list at that point (basically, this
                                         divides the list at the second ' without removing anything)
                         ¥/          - Then, reduce (apply to first and second as left and right) by
                      ;ß}            - Concatenating the left side with this function applied to the right link
                            ¹        Otherwise, if ' and " aren't found, just return the string itself
```
````

Comment: can we get an explanation of how it works?

Comment: @NooneAtAll I usually don't do much work on answers anymore after they've been beaten by so much, but here you go.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
⁾'"iⱮnaoɗ\ŻṖoƊỊx@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsIwEIb3PEW45SaHpGOx@BqCyyU4KMWuulUXoQ@giy7OIigOlYJLseBjJC8Sk4bidN//3X@3nOf5xjm7fSMs7P22ouJ7nH0a8zoUXWWaaj1xqS1PfJRxW57Tds9M8zT1w9SXdt9VdnedOidkwscZ94MJkBBDYPgvUEgMHKYPIDEBiCJwryDBwXhkBAJDjYIkYkCgQPdHiiGhQh37ERkheADUfX8I/g36O4Solf4B)

A link taking a Jelly string argument and returning a Jelly string without the comments.

### Explanation

```
⁾'"iⱮ              | Positions of each character in '" (so single quote -> 1, double quote -> 2, anything else -> 0)
         ɗ\        | Cumulative reduce (x,y)
     nao           | - (x != y) and (x or y)
              Ɗ    | Following as a monad:
           Ż       | - Prepend zero
            Ṗ      | - Remove last item from list
             o     | - Or
               Ị   | Less than or equal to 1
                x@ | Original input with 0 or 1 copies of each character as appropriate
```

Comment: sadly you missed the fgitw :/

Comment: @Wzl what do you mean?

Comment: fastest gun in the west

Answer (score 4):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS) `g`, <s>18</s> 12 bytes

‒6 thanks to Neil.

```
'.*'
".*"
&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxCsAwDMR2P0NDDzIEkrzISaFzC32/63QR4nT36@cToVpk1IIdFtH6sEZnk3S1rgRdA35hyJymvbjhTFYW19TKIlLQyo8yiRXXBw)

This is equivalent to the Dyalog APL function `'''.*''' '".*"'⎕R'&' ''⍠'Greedy'0`

The `g` flag turns off greedy patterns, essentially making `*` mean `*?`. Then the two patterns simply replace `'.*'` strings and `".*"` comments with `&` themselves and  nothing, respectively.

Comment: okay now we've gotten regex out of the way :P

Comment: No non-greedy quantifiers?

Comment: @Neil Wouldn't make a difference, as `'[^']*'` matches *exactly* all the chars between `'` and the next `'`. The important thing is that the two patterns run in parallel, with, for each starting position, preference for the first one.

Comment: Sure, but Retina lets me use `'.*?'` which is shorter.

Comment: @Neil D'uh, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

```
c;s;main(){while((c=getchar())+1)s=s?s-2?putchar(c):0,s*(c!=44-5*s):c-34?putchar(c)==39:2;}
```

All my submissions so far have been in esolangs, so even though C might not be anything groundbreaking, it's at least new to me. :)

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBCsIwFET3vYWz@Uk1YJK6sCH0LL@f0hZqEaO4EM8eU924eTzmjRhZeB1zlpDChedV6ddzmpdBKYnjcJeJb0rrvdUppi4Z110fv1F0ezykWskuNo051Um3Ynzz12P059aFd87W@crCYSOKk3VUAEce@Ao8VQxL28IVGD2kFKaepBRCEZCUD5VEkA8)

#### Explanation

```
c;s;                          // for current char and state
main() {
  while ((c=getchar())+1)     // while input is not EOF:
    s=s?            // if state is not 0 (0=default, 1=string literal, 2=comment)
      s-2?putchar(c):0,       // output the current char if state is not 2
      s*(c!=44-5*s) // set s to 0 if the relevant character is found
                    // (39 ['] if state = 1, 34 ["] if state = 2)
     :              // else (state = 0)
      c-34?         // if the current char is not ["]
        putchar(c)==39 // output current char, and if it is ['], set s to 1
       :      // else (current char is ["])
        2     // set s to 2
    ;}        // end expression, statement, and main function
```

Comment: Looks great! Would you mind adding a "readable" version as well?

Comment: No problem, although I'm not sure how 'readable' I can make it.

Answer (score 4):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), <s>118</s> <s>113</s> 112 bytes

```
LINE INPUT s$
FOR i=1TO LEN(s$)
a=ASC(MID$(s$,i))
k=c
c=c XOR(a=34)<q
q=q XOR(a=39)<c
IF c+k=0THEN?CHR$(a);
NEXT
```

#### Explanation

Looping over the ASCII code `a` of each character in a line of input `s$`, we track three boolean values:

- `c` is true inside a comment, false otherwise
- `q` is true inside quotes, false otherwise
- `k` is the previous iteration's value of `c` (we need to track this so we can suppress both double quotes instead of just the first one)

The values are updated as follows:

- If the current character is a double quote (`a=34`) and `q` is false, toggle `c`
- If the current character is a single quote (`a=39`) and `c` is false, toggle `q`

If both `c` and `k` are false, we're not in a comment, so output the character.

(There's a fun trick in the update statements: In QBasic, truthy is -1, so instead of `a=39AND c=0`, we can get the same result from `(a=39)<c`. The inequality will be true only when `a=39` is `-1` and `c` is `0`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), no regex, <s>75</s> 65 bytes

```python
a=b=1
for i in input():c=b*i;a^="'"==c;b^='"'==a*i;print(end=c*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7RCoMwDEXf@xUlL7G@tb6MSn5FaGOHhVGLdky/3sUxSEK453KTerZlLcOjbhevcyIAuAJFsuq5bjrrXKTqu3XGM8U@j2EiQCDiMU6EgERB1Lrl0rpUZuI@mktSVNtOr/Rnya@krU9H4u6@YP5eo9LBqTZfw75f1g3KgoN7guxoHcoAh4NE4Q@hCmDxVoKCABFYSMCILEQ@idIsHhSEwF8)

Much cleaner solution than my previous one

#### how it works :

`a` and `b` store the state of the string:

- `a` is equal to `0` if the char is inside a literal and `1` otherwise
- `b` is equal to `0` if the char is inside a comment and `1` otherwise
- `c` store the char multiplied by `b`. If  the char is inside a comment (`b` is equal to `0`), `c` is equal to the empty string
- `a^=` use of the bitwise operator xor to swich the state of `a` if the current char is `'` and the char is not inside a comment
- same goes for `b` but with `"`
- `print(end=c*b)` print the char if `b` is not set to `0`. `end=` is for avoiding the trailing new line

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), regex, 52 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub("\".*?\"|('.*?')","\\1",s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMgFET3nkJm87UEqWZTCqUXcWMSQ4XEiNpFoXe3ppuZx7xJn/o64nhLua0P2za3T4vj5Z69Ku9JwEJdnhZfQb1JYoC1GkORLOzpyJVn39Yj88BD5EfyUVylyt4tQqqStlC3EH0R8s54yiFWsYogZdNmZBoGZ6IzaUM9YGgE/oCRmIOmc3EMDhPmbhxNNHdD6ACa@4e6Isw/)

Pretty basic:  I replace comments by nothing and literals by themselves. Regex substitution are not overriding. Lazy operators do the rest

Comment: any particular reason for putting the import after the lambda? I guess it makes no difference; I've just never seen it before

Comment: It's for the TIO link. I can add `f=\ ` in the header to name my lambda function. But yeah, it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/('|").*?\1/g,_=>_<'%'?'':_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzdToNAFITveQpyEjO7LYLAjTFC73wBL9VuDtulwSBUtjUx8d1xf2y8OjPfmZl3/mKrl@F0vp3mg1n7ZrVNa/PFnEbWRhQCPyTzze61LI6Zalr1iBvsgAcl18V8XobFCPQW0lX48DSM5vl70uIuw@Xc3wf8t7R/2adv2@IjzOh5svNo8nE@CpWlwLYXSkq5llWdNm3qTlJSRdF4Tf8PlBW89tcZqlATReB1QFTjSpxMmEr4GHvInBBTRzqUugSMDjrmo0wY5ARBh/zVuBm4HijiTv8C)

Trivial, thank  EliteDaMyth for -3 bytes

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>88</s> 86 bytes, No RegEx

```javascript
f=([c,...s],y=c=='"')=>c?[[c+s.splice(0,s.indexOf(c=="'"|y?c:s)+1).join``][+y]]+f(s):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZAxb4MwEIV3fgW65WxBnQJLFMnJ1rVDR0SIOUzkiALFSVWk/nd6gKIO1r33@d2z5Jv5Np5GN9xfur6289xokVOslPJFPGnSGgGlPtIpzynyyg@tIyteY69cV9uf90ZwBhB@pxMdvIwSqW696y6XIo@mooga4eXBz6P9erjRCmw8SjVaU7@51n5MHXEXPu7NfsVDa7h9d87PYRHtPq9xyU/3ne9bq9r@Kso4ROTOUko5J2kW6mPII0gghc0sGv4vMElx0ctkAylmABtY9IogwydhGRhIcImZBRoTgIEKaF2qAjRYIW35TQaGf6jiQ2v@abgGeQ9hwxX9AQ)

If `s.indexOf(s)` happens to be non-negative, then `s==c` and `f([c,c])==c+c`

Comment: What does the argument l do?

Comment: @ophact The remaining part of the string

Comment: [48 bytes, you dont need the brackets around the `(c=='"'.....)`, also replaces `(['"])` with `('|")`](https://tio.run/##RY/BTsMwEETv/opoL2vTkODkgpCc3vgBjkCjtetEQSEpcYuE1H8P65iKg7Uzzzsj7Qd9U3DLcDrfT/PRr51Zg2lCsfjTSM7LUuIVVHG3f9PXouxz2eZOmcYZg4B7xKdWrYv/ugyLl9gFVJyk4/Mw@pefycmHHC/n7nHDf4WH10P2vis/@7zlnnkK8@iLce65OUPcdbJVSq26qjPTZDyEhgqSiRr@P1BXGHWcbKDCGiCBqDcENd4IS0GgMa5RhEQCCCy4LWQFElp0aT9JQXyl5ee2/ZvhGuQcQsLW/QI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 16 bytes

```
('.*?')|".*?"
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxDYBADAP7jGEhGSiQkh@AWfIRBQ0FomT3kKexTz7fx3NenjlzW3cuL6ogk2aqNVEYRqKYaqyAsQE/oFEcyrG4wNERZZydUYYoAKM@LEXEBw) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Regex, obviously. Since by default matches can't overlap, the regex can match both strings and comments and won't get confused. It then remains to delete the comments without changing the strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔ωζＦＳ«Ｆ¬⁼∨ζι"ι¿№"'ι≔⁻∨ζι∧ζιζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY27DsIwDEVn@hWRFztS@QKmCjEw8JBYWUpL20BI2jxaKOLbQ6AMbL6@xz5Fk5tC5zKEzFpRKxpSNvJFUmnDaK1a7w7OCFUT5@yZzL7rrXa06nwuLe0MjSkTPGVwBOAR2kfakYgvZqJitNQ@xlgifDjOfpqNUP7/PFPlNPLJ/wohhxMWUOIZKqyhQQEXvILEGyjU0GIHBi049NDjAHd8hHkv3w) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ωζ
```

Keep track of the current quote character, initially , but can be `"` or `'`.

```
ＦＳ«
```

Loop over the input.

```
Ｆ¬⁼∨ζι"ι
```

If the current quote, or the current character if there is no current quote, is not `"`, then print the current character.

```
¿№"'ι
```

If the current character is a quote, then...

```
≔⁻∨ζι∧ζιζ
```

... turn the current quote on or off as appropriate.

- If the current quote is empty, then we subtract nothing from the current character, so the current quote becomes the current character.
- Otherwise, we subtract the current character from the current quote. This ends the current quote only once we find the matching character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 105 bytes

```hs
f('"':s)=g s
f(a@'\'':s)=a:h s
f(a:s)=a:f s
f[]=[]
g('"':s)=f s
g(a:s)=g s
h(a@'\'':s)=a:f s
h(a:s)=a:h s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFPa4QwEMXvfoohFCaCW9C9LaQUepZ@AONhYv1H3bgYL/30Nsl03ZVeEt/vzXsBZyD33U7TNl5v87LCx2zXZZ5ey9nSF8huXsoUTif4tNMPeAUDLbZ1buskCry4VPXgkk7SO2qMmi4DExZdEFWtqjrp75HAeh4I6eGQ7pjsVVtDrnWgEoAKpMiLs8ggXqlHWUBaFFowPlDP/w1jXmBg8X5AP4rnkGAvyqPtX8DdjOJukxY5xjiFAaLd0cEzWjTcax6NhAYb7vv73NtQC0/80cS2J/n0IMZef/KQYbNOkiuNFlRYVQn8515AS8rA@D2@wW0Z7er3CgRKgckgOtsv)

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript's type system, 142 bytes

```typescript
type F<S>=S extends`'${infer Z}'${infer X}`?`'${Z}'${F<X>}`:S extends`"${any}"${infer X}`?F<X>:S extends`${infer C}${infer X}`?`${C}${F<X>}`:S
```

[Try it at the TS playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAZQHwF4FQgD2BAdgEwGcADAcgBIBvAS1wDMIAnKALQF8Kb6moANN4gH4yVdp3i8kAgFzosOAiQBEVAIa4QbFVwbN+QiUlkZseIsSq1dUAMJtL3PQOFU7VQzIQAoL6EhQAFQhCYABGKBRYOGJQgCYAZmIkLwB6FKgMgD1BX3BoIJDYiKiYpVilROS0jKhs3P8C4Hji+FKyytT0rJy-fODgABYW6NI40iTOmrrewP6AVmGyULLSeKUlCeru+r6QgDZF0bKK8aqu2p682ZCAdkXVJVDSWNWlVU3z6avGgA5Ft6UACMlABjDZnKaXBr9ACch1UpEBpBBp0m2xmjVCAAZ7qQlIi8ciPpCdtcwuFIq0HnjgXiQcTtkA)

This is a type F that takes and outputs a string type.

Explanation:

```typescript
type F<S>=
```

This is the type signature for F. S is the input string type, but since this is a recursive type, S isn't necessarily the original string, but rather whatever part of the string we haven't processed yet.

```typescript
S extends`'${infer Z}'${infer X}`?`'${Z}'${F<X>}`
```

Attempt to match S against: single quote + a string called Z + single quote + a string called X. If the match succeeded, return single quote + Z + single quote + recurse, with X as the argument.

This step keeps anything within single quotes.

```typescript
:S extends`"${any}"${infer X}`?F<X>
```

If the match failed, attempt to match S against: double quote + a string + double quote + a string called X. If the match succeeded, recurse with X as the argument.

This step discards anything between double quotes.

```typescript
:S extends`${infer C}${infer X}`?`${C}${F<X>}`
```

If that match failed, match S against: a character called C + a string called X. This basically just extracts the first character and the rest. If the match succeeded, return C + recurse with X as the argument.

```typescript
:S
```

If that match failed, S must be the empty string, so we just return it because the program has finished.

Note that this solution isn't tail recursive, so it only works for strings under 50 characters. Here's a tail recursive version that works for strings up to 999 characters:

### TypeScript's type system, 166 bytes

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type F<S,O="">=S extends`'${infer Z}'${infer X}`?F<X,`${O}'${Z}'`>:S extends`"${any}"${infer X}`?F<X,O>:S extends`${infer C}${infer X}`?F<X,`${O}${C}`>:O
```

[Try it at the TS playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAMQB4BlAGgHkBeAInoD5bzD0APcdRAE0gAGAcgAkAb1iIAZulSEAWgF9RE6bMIANRQID8ZDZQHjqy8UqECmALjadufQfXEBDRDkVPVMuVt36a1rZcPPxGXuoAworikt6a2nqkBmEm4lGWVtSY2PhEACrokOAAjIS0JKQCxQBMAMyWmCCEzQB6OjkEhAVF1WUVVfTV9PVMjcDNhG0d+YXgtX1kA4MjYxNTuJ3d4AAsC5VCNRajTa3tGzNFAKx7wsWDQrWMDSeTZ7ldswBsNweDw0erU7TD5FADsN2c9GKQmqD3ozme4yB5xB4AAHDd4fQAEb0ADG9ERazem1mAE4fs4hNihHiAS91u8tsUAAwQoT0akc2lE5FM2bFUrlRaQjm4jl43mvTBAA)